# Using source as a verb to mean "to provide a citation"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

Recently on the meta for English.se, I used the following sentence:

> Personally, I think we should **source** answers if possible, but this is also sensitive to the level of the asker.

My question relates to whether this usage of **source** as a verb is as one person responded "a rather lazy and hence unclear phrase?"

The other person suggested that it could admit two interpretations:

> we should provide sources in answers

OR

> we should seek answers

---

google defines source as a verb as follows:

> obtain from a particular source.

I learned to use source in the way I describe in the midst of university teaching. Specifically, we often say regarding claims that are not original to a student or that state data without a citation -- "you need to source this."

Is something in my usage odd, incorrect, or lazy?

Comment: Not to me. But some people still stick to the notion that evening weirds language and will probably think this is awkward. As always, the yardstick we measure ‘proper language’ by is what our parents speak/spoke—and if they were against it, likely the kids will be, too.

Comment: Is "English.se" for foreign speakers of English? If so, then many EFL speakers might have difficulty with your example use of "source". But for native English speakers, your usage is fine (according to me, AmE speaker). :)

Comment: I don't see a problem. The site still says it's for [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If anyone doesn't understand simple (and relatively commonplace) extensions like that, they should probably be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) in the first place. But my gut feeling is this question is POB here, and should probably be moved to meta (where we *are* supposed to discuss things like this).

Comment: No, you **just can't** do that. Think of it, and it may start becoming clear to you as to why not. And it's such pity, I need to leave the desk right now, though I wish I could post an answer rightaway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing inherently wrong with employing *source* as a verb in either your sense or the commercial sense which Google afforded you.

It earned this sense by exactly the same process which gave rise to the established academic term *to document*, a similarly verbed noun which similarly is open to two constructions: to provide references to existing corroborative sources or to create a record which will constitute future corroborative sources.

Your only concern should be what audience you are addressing—some will consider your use of *source* breezily fresh, others cheesily faddish—and whether you care how they take it.

For the time being, *source* is slang and *document* is jargon. You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Comment: +1 However, the question is rather different. Perhaps a re-read may be worth.

Comment: @kris, maybe I'm lost here, but this sounds exactly like an answer to my question. The only possibility other than this is that I would need you to tell me what my question is.

Comment: @kris I've added something which addresses what I infer you found to be the critical issue.

Comment: What do you mean that "source is slang"?

Comment: @nxx *Source* is a fairly novel term (it was not in use when I was in graduate school 40 years ago), it is a non-standard term (the standard term is *document*), it is employed colloquially (in the first 150 Google Books hits on "sourced":21st century, I find only 1 which may be construed to bear this sense), and it appears to be restricted to a fairly narrow circle of users (academics). That's pretty much the definition of slang.

Comment: @StoneyB Okay thanks. I've always known it as a widely used and understood term in academic contexts (I wasn't even born 40 years ago), plus it seems to be supported as standard by MW (see my answer). Actually, I've never heard "document" to mean "to provide references" (only "to record"). Maybe there's also a BrE/AmE usage difference.

Comment: @nxx Could be. The 'Bible' in my field is the *M[odern]L[anguage]A[ssociation] Style Manual ...*. Chh. 6 and 7 are titled "Documentation: Preparing the List of Works Cited" and "Documentation: Citing Sources in the Text".

Comment: @StoneyB Is it a contemporary edition?

Comment: @nxx The most recent - I gave it to my wife when she started graduate school two years ago. But 'documentation' has been the standard term as far back as I can remember. (Though you have to be careful about what 60s college students remember; there was a *lot* of drugs around back then.)

Comment: @StoneyB Haha. Thanks for the info. Would love to hear more from older vs younger and BrE vs AmE people about this.

Answer (score 1):

"we should source answers", with the definition you have given, means that we should seek to obtain the answers - not provide the sources for the information in the answers.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/source) offers both that definition and this one:

> to specify the source of

which seems to be the definition you want. As you say, this is common usage in the academic context, and makes "we should source answers" perfectly correct.

Going with your definition, an alternative could be "we should cite sources in our answers", which is less ambiguous than using "source" as a verb.